# Is "Roh-eh Hanoled" a classical expression?

Tags: words, jewish-books, pentateuch-chumash

In Maus from Art Spiegelman, a rabbi tells Vladek he's a "Roh-eh Hanoled", *one that sees what the future holds*. It is an invention of his or does it exist in any classical or sacred source ?

Comment: Check out Avot 2:9

Comment: this article deals with it but I don't have an account with them https://www.jstor.org/stable/42943714?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents the phrase haro'eh es hanolad is from Ethics of the Fathers 2:9 about someone who considers the consequences of his action https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not his invention. The phrase appears in the [Mishnah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah) in Tractate [Avot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirkei_Avot) in Chapter 2 Mishnah #9 or #10 (depending on your version):

> אמר להם צאו וראו איזוהי דרך ישרה שידבק בה האדם רבי אליעזר אומר עין
>   טובה רבי יהושע אומר חבר טוב רבי יוסי אומר שכן טוב **רבי שמעון אומר הרואה
>   את הנולד** רבי אלעזר אומר לב טוב אמר להם רואה אני את דברי אלעזר בן ערך
>   שבכלל דבריו דבריכם
>
> [Rabbi Yochanan] said to them: Go and see which is the best trait for
>   a person to acquire. Said Rabbi Eliezer: A good eye. Said Rabbi
>   Joshua: A good friend. Said Rabbi Yossei: A good neighbor. **Said
>   Rabbi Shimon: To see what is born [out of ones actions].** Said Rabbi
>   Elazar: A good heart. Said He to them: I prefer the words of Elazar
>   the son of Arach to yours, for his words include all of yours.
>   ([Chabad.org translation; my emphasis](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2011/jewish/Chapter-Two.htm))

The bolded phrase transliterated is:

> Rabbi Shimon Omer **ha'roeh et hanolad**

Comment: Also Tamid 32a - איזהו חכם הרואה את הנולד

Comment: @DonielF True, but that's post-Mishnaic.

Comment: Technically yes, and [potentially post-Gemara as well](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84656/9682). However, the context is an interaction between the Rabbis and Alexander the Great, placing it earlier than the Mishnah quoted.

Comment: And why does the Mishna call a midwife a *chachamah*? Because she's *ro'ah es hanolad.* (Remind me which Acharon supposedly said this as a child?)

Answer (score 1):

The expression is traced to mishnaic times as mentioned in the other answer. The concept however is older.

See [Koheles 2:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.2.14?with=Rashi&lang=bi)

> הֶֽחָכָם֙ עֵינָ֣יו בְּרֹאשׁ֔וֹ

> A wise man has his eyes in his head

As Rashi there explains:

> The wise man, his eyes are in his head. In the beginning [=בְּרֹאשׁוֹ of the matter, he contemplates the end results.